# Calculating an area between circles with Double Integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Hey I need to answer the following question:

find the **area** of

- $D=[(x,y):(x-1)^2+y^2\leq 1, x^2+y^2\geq 1,0\leq y\leq x] $

I know how to solve this kind of problems with normal integrals but how do i manage to calculate it with double integral? 
I tried to use the polar technique but i dont sure im doing it right
Thank you!

Comment: What did you get for the bounds of $D$ in polar coordinates?

Comment: $0\leq \Theta \leq \pi/4$ and $1\leq r\leq 2cos\theta$

Comment: I like it, it turns out to be $\frac12 +\frac{\pi}{8}$.

Answer (score 1):

You got the correct bounds $0 \le \theta \le \dfrac{\pi}{4}$ and $1 \le r \le 2\cos \theta$, as you stated in your comment.

Now, all you need to do is compute the integral $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\int_{1}^{2\cos\theta}r\,dr\,d\theta$.

The inner integral is straightforward. Once you do that, the outer integral can be done easily after using the identity $2\cos^2\theta - 1 = \cos 2\theta$.

Comment: (Should it be $\cos 2\theta$ instead of $\sin 2\theta$?)

Comment: @user84413: Thanks for that correction.

Answer (score 0):

Do it using polars. Just integrate from $-\pi/3$ to $\pi/4$ the integrand 
$(1/2)[4cos^2(\theta)-1]d\theta$. The reason is the area is lying between the circle $r=1, r=2cos(\theta)$ and below the line $\theta=\pi/4$. The intersection point is $(1/2,-\sqrt3/2)$. Use double angle formula.